# How to resize jQuery accordion once content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I've got a jQuery UI accordion which will eventually contain several
forms. To keep my HTML file from becoming insanely unreadable, I want
to toss each form into a separate file and load them. From another
Stack Overflow question/answer I got this, which works well:

```
...
<head>
  ...
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#form1").load("form1.html");
      $("#form2").load("form2.html");
      $("#form3").load("form3.html");
    });
  </script>
  ...
</head>

<body>
...
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Form 1</h3><div id="form1"></div>
  <h3>Form 2</h3><div id="form2"></div>
  <h3>Form 3</h3><div id="form3"></div>
</div>
...
</body>
```

Unfortunately, the accordion's size appears to be computed before the
various formN.html files are loaded. How do I force it to recompute
the accordion's size after those files have been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `refresh` method. Since you have 3 separate ajax requests I would do something like:

```
var f1=$("#form1").load("form1.html");
var f2=$("#form2").load("form2.html");
var f3=$("#form3").load("form3.html");

$.when(f1,f2,f3).then(function(){
   /* all forms loaded now we can refresh accordion */
   $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');
});
```

[accordion refresh() docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh)